# c++ compiler that uses source control for its resources

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Is there such a thing as a source control compiler that would pull down the necessary files into a local repo based on third party repos that you specify and pass that to a linker?

Comment: Its not a just a compiler now, are u looking for continuous integration systems?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a build automation systems. The build system incorporates elements of pulling code from source control, and calling others programs, such as compiler and linker, executing tests etc. You can yourself write a rudimentary build automation system using shell scripts. Else look at tools like Maven, Ant, Hudson etc.